# Varnish default VCL access control list

Tags: apache, caching, varnish

After adding a simple acl to the top of default.vcl to restrict purge requests to localhost, Varnish fails to restart. My default VCL is otherwise unmodified. default.vcl is as follows:

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}

acl purge {
  "localhost";
}
```

It doesn't matter if I place the acl declaration above or below the backend directive. Varnish version 3.0.2.

This should be an otherwise exteremely simple configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run varnishd in debug mode and it should show you where the error is. Example:

```
# varnishd -d -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl

Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
('input' Line 32 Pos 6)
     resp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=60";
-----#######################----------------
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the line causing the problem. The VCL syntax for purging has changed on V3. https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the compile flag (-C) to find any syntax errors in your VCL. This won't startup any servers, it simply compiles the VCL into C and prints the output.

```
varnishd -C -f /etc/varnish/main.vcl
```